# Image manager (picasa like)

Tags: command-line, image-processing, google-picasa, image-editor

I'm trying to find an image viewer/manager which should have two main features:

1. Its fast in displaying/load images. gpicview is fair good at this task but doesn't have the second point...
2. I need a way to make a list of those images I'm intrested in (for a later processing) from the ones I'm looking at. Maybe you could suggest a way to findout which image is being displayed currently by gpicview, that would be also fine.
   Picasa was once a very good tool for this but I'm not able to make it run (picasa3 ) for AMD 64 bits.

Can anyone suggest an image viewer which would alow me to create a list of images for those I'm intresting in?

Any other aproaches to achieve same are also welcome.

There are plenty questions and posts about fast image viewers but didn't manage so far to find something to fullfill p. 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do for you although its a bit rudimentary. I bet it will perform enough to fulfill your first requirement, though ;>

[feh](https://feh.finalrewind.org/) is an image viewer with many options (see [man page](https://man.finalrewind.org/1/feh/)), one of which is the **-A** or **--action** option, which allows you to execute a script if you hit the *action_0* key (RETURN by default, can be configured).

**Example of your second usecase:**

```
cd ~/Pictures/
# create a folder for selection
mkdir selection01
# tell feh to link files to that folder when action is triggered
feh *-2016.jpg -A "ln -s ../%F ./selection01/"
```

You can easily write a script to call with the action in order to toggle (remove and link) the files you want to collect and maybe use something like notify-send to give you some feedback via GUI.